AWS Using cloudfront to forward PUT requests to S3 (including V4 signature)
I am uploading a file to an S3 bucket using PUT request and AWS V4 Signature, all working well and tested in Postman. The request looks like this...
PUT https://example.com/to-process/test.json?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Date=20240415T033843Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATGD6OWCXBG3WY4FF%2F20240415%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=766f0a30fb6702597706d1cb8d88f9f8ea2de2334acf7ecdfce51b0bfdf07412

Now I need to change the behaviour so that depending on the requests URL path, some requests go to S3 and some go to an EC2 server, so I am using Cloudfront with multiple origins and behaviours...this works ok for the ec2 origin but the S3 origin requests give a 400 response
400 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

I have the following cloudfront setup...

I have set the 'Origin Access' to public
I have disabled WAF and Origin Shield
I have set Allowed Http
Methods to 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE'
Restrict Viewer Access - No
Cache Policy - 'Caching Disabled'
Origin Request Policy - 'AllViewerExceptHostHeader'

I have also tried adding the signature params as headers instead of query params, this gives the same response
Looking at the CF access logs it is not logging anything for the 400 responses so I can't see what the problem might be
The S3 bucket is set to 'Block all public access'
Can anyone advise on why CF is rejecting these requests?
UPDATE:
I managed to get the request through (they are now showing in the CF Access logs) however I am getting 403 errors related to the Signature:
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>

I assume this is because the request is being signed (by Postman) using my custom domain as the host and Cloudfront is forwarding the request onto S3, S3 is using the bucket endpoint to calculate the signature. I have tried various solutions of passing the Host header to the Origin and forcing a different Host via Postman, but still get the same issue
